# Share sane scanner over network so Windows can access it

Tags: drivers, printer, scanner, windows-11

I have two printer/scanners (both Brother MFC-2700DW) and I also have some windows 11 computers and a Mac that's not critical to support but Id still like to. The drivers + windows 11 don't really work with the scanners. However, Ubuntu + drivers works great. I know I can share these using SANE if I install a sane client on windows but the windows SANE clients look crusty to say the least. I would much prefer to just advertise the scanner with a protocol that windows can natively handle (WSD) and Mac can handle natively (eSCL).

**Is there a way to share the scanners in with WSD?**

EDIT: WSD is enabled on the Brother and it hooks up to the network. The problem is that it doesn't actually fully work. It will print most of the time but when it comes to scanning I can only consistently scan A4 sized pages. When I scan Letter it breaks like 40% of the time and as I scan more pages at the same time the failure goes up. Again, it works with linux just fine.

Also I already fully updated the firmware.

PS: I did ask this question on stackoverflow but I don't think that was the right place for it. If you think this should also be on ServerFault tell me.

UPDATE: I found a [project](https://github.com/SimulPiscator/AirSane) that allows me to share via eSCL. I haven't tested it yet but I am beginning to think that eSCL isn't supported on windows. So it's, unfortunately, not the whole solution.

Comment: You can use "scan to PC" on these printers instead. Setup on computers sharable folder and from web interface of this printer - add network location of workstations, then you can send scans directly to particular machine.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is my plan b. However, I'd still like to have everything just work if at all possible.

Comment: Did you tried `C:\Windows\System32\wfs.exe` ?

Comment: Yep. It doesn't work.

Comment: Login then into Brother's web interface and check there in the setting if WSD is enabled

Comment: It is. I can connect to it with the windows computer via WSD but when I do that I can only consistently scan successfully when the page size is A4. I live in the US so I need Letter. When I scan Letter it works about 40% of the time and that success rate scales inversely to the number of pages I need to scan. Look I've been working on this for days. Please try to answer the original question.

Comment: The free [SaneTwain project](https://sanetwain.ozuzo.net/) from 2013 might still work on Windows 10. If it's worth some dozens of dollars, you could try if [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/) has a better Windows driver for your printer.

Comment: "I know I can share these using SANE if I install a sane client on windows but the windows SANE clients look crusty to say the least" Plus this is on windows 11. VueScan looks kinda promising, thanks for that.

Comment: I don't know if SaneTwain will work for you, but it doesn't use a windows SANE client. It has its own socket communication layer, talking directly with the SANE net backend. With Twain, every Windows application that does scanning will just work.

Comment: "talking directly with SANE net backend" That is the definition of a sane client in the client/server relationship sense of "client".

Comment: Yes, but at least it's not one of the crusty ones that you tried.

Comment: It is actually exactly one of the crusty ones I was referring to.

Comment: Has VueScan worked out for you?

Comment: It's kinda expensive for my liking and kind of not the right way to go about things. I don't like clients because I need a client for everyone who's using the printer whereas a server everyone can access out of the box. Given that, I think I'm just going to write my own.

Comment: Last I checked AirSane did not support sheet feeders. On the other hand, Twain2Airscan from ScannerShare.com does support sheetfeeders from shared windows scanner to eSCL . I have it planned to do the same to share a Linux scanner via eSCL (sane2airscan) but I just have not got there yet. Too many projects and working alone. It should be easy enough to switch my code from talking twain command line to sane command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI

You can now take a working TWAIN or WIA Scanner connected to Windows and share  it with Linux(Sane-AirScan), MacOS(Native), Android(Mopria Scan), iOS(AirScanner App) and ChromeOS(Mopria Scan) over the eSCL / AirScan Protocol. The solution is free for personal use. It is called Twain2AirScan and is the flagship product at http://scannershare.com where you can download it. It does require a web server on a Windows machine . Was tested extensively on Windows 10 64 Bit with Brother 8710DW MFP. Because there is no real working Generic eSCL client for Windows though you can not use it to share between Windows computers.

see http://scannershare.com

Yes we need an eSCL driver for Windows. Are you listening Microsoft?

Comment: Uhhhh that domain looks like it expired and got taken over by a very seedy Japanese site. Any alternative recommendations?